# Heroku Git Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1: java 11

Tags: spring, maven, heroku, compilation

I am trying to deploy my spring application to heroku.
I wanted to use heroku git as in tutorial on heroku.
I did:

```
git add .
git commit -am "make it better"
git push heroku master
```

but I am getting error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) on project projectName: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
```

So I spent about 2 hourse to solve it by any dependencies and changes in properties but nothing help.
When I run mvn clean install in Intelijj Build is success - without ny error.
That error only appears in cmd when I want to push it to master...
Shortcut of my pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.4</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>projectName</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    …
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.22</version>
    </dependency>
        …
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```